# ¿Cuándo se debe usar una interfaz y no una clase (y viceversa)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Cuando programamos con Typescript, tenemos un concepto que no existe en Javascript: interfaces. En ES6 hay clases, que son *azúcar sintáctico* para el prototipado clásico, pero no hay tipado de variables y nada parecido a una interfaz.

Uno puede pensar que las interfaces son lo mismo que en Java o C#, pero me he encontrado con esto:

```
class MiClase {

  constructor( public atributoA: string) {}

  metodoA() {
    //hace algo
  }
}

interface MiInterfaz extends MiClase {
    algo: any;
}

function miFuncion(attr: MiClase) {
  console.log(attr instanceof MiClase);
}

function miFuncion2(attr: MiInterfaz) {
  console.log(attr instanceof MiClase);
}

let a = {
    atributoA: 'hola',
    atributoB: 6,
    metodoA: function () { },
};


miFuncion(a); //false
miFuncion2(a);//false

let b = new MiClase('Una auténtica instancia de MiClase');

miFuncion(b); //true
miFuncion2(b);//compilador marca error, no cumple la interfaz
```

¿Qué está pasando aquí?

- ¿Por qué `a` no da error al usarla en `miFuncion` cuando claramente no es de la clase `MiClase`?
- ¿Por qué son intercambiables? ¡La interfaz extiende una clase y no da error!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ¿Por qué `a` no da error al usarla en `miFuncion` cuando claramente no es
>   de la clase `MiClase`?

`a`  es un objecto anónimo por lo que nunca sera de la instancia del tipo `MiClase`.

Si lo intentas en javascript verás que también te retorna `false`:

```js
function MiClase(valor){
   this.atributo = valor;
}

var aninimo = {atributo: 4};
var instancia = new MiClase(4);

console.log(aninimo instanceof MiClase);
console.log(instancia instanceof MiClase);
```

El verificador de tipo de typescript **se centra en la forma en como el valor/objecto está definido**, no en su tipo. A esto se le llama [duck typing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). De ahí que este caso el compilador no te lance ningún error:

```
let a = {
    atributoA: 'hola',
    atributoB: 6,
    metodoA: function () { },
};

miFuncion(a); //false
```

[Segun la documentacion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> El compilador solo verifica que al menos las propiedades definidas en la interfaz estén
>   presentes y coincidan con los tipos requeridos.

Como `a` si tiene las propiedades requeridas por la interfaz/clase `MiClase`, el compilador te lo permite.

> ¿Por qué son intercambiables? ¡La interfaz extiende una clase y no da
>   error!

Como ya se mencionó, typescript no se centra en el tipo, sino en la forma en como el tipo esta definido, por lo que cuando una interfaz extiende de una clase simplemente estas agregándole a la interfaz la forma de clase que hereda.

En resumen, para saber cuando utilizar una interfaz o clase se siguen utilizando los mismos principios de siempre y así evitar confusión:

1. Si necesitas definir un contrato para definir distintos
   comportamientos con la misma interfaz o necesitas soportar herencia
   múltiple, utilizas una interface.
2. Si necesitas una implementación en especifica(como por ejemplo una
   clase factory), utilizas una clase.

Comment: Gran explicación, muchas gracias!